# New to Visual Basic, Need help making background timers

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2010, timer

I just started Visual Basic for school, the class is moving really slowly and I'm not learning very much so I'm trying to get ahead and do some experimenting. 
I'm trying to make a clone game of Cookie Clicker and I need to make the Clicks per Second work
I tried using the built in timer and doing a simple addition statement in the code but realized quickly that the built in timer only works if it alone is being used. I cant make it run in the background while I am running the game.

I tried working with the system.threading.thread.timer but was not very successful because I am new to VB. Here is my current code

```
Public Class window
    Dim varcookies As Integer = 0
    Dim varcps As Decimal = 0
    Dim varclickercost As Decimal = 10
    Dim varclicker As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Cookie_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cookie.Click
        varcookies = varcookies + 1
        Me.CookiesVal.Text = varcookies

    End Sub

    Private Sub window_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Me.CPSVal.Text = varcps
        Me.CookiesVal.Text = varcps
        Me.btnclicker.Text = varclickercost
        Me.clock.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnclicker.Click

        If varcookies >= varclickercost Then
            varcookies = varcookies - varclickercost
            varcps = varcps + 0.5
            varclicker = varclicker + 1
            varclickercost = varclickercost * 1.5
            Me.Clickers.Text = varclicker
            Me.btnclicker.Text = varclickercost
            Me.CookiesVal.Text = varcookies
            Me.CPSVal.Text = varcps
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

any help would be appreciated to get the timer thread working.

Before this comes up, this is not homework, I am just doing this for fun. In class we are currently exploring the wide expanses of text boxes.

Thanks :)

Comment: Firstly Where is your timer code? and what exactly is your error or problem. Secondly it looks like this is a WinForms Application so I would look into using System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead.

Comment: I deleted the timer code because i couldn't get anything to work. That's why I requested help. The timer control runs on the same thread as the form so if I use it, it wont run at the same time as anything else on the form.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the timer works:

1. The timer is enabled or started (a timer method).
2. It runs for its specified interval (a timer property).
3. It raises a timer.Tick event and calls the event handler.

For example, you might set the interval to 1000 milliseconds, then write the code you want to be executed once per second and place it in the timer.click handler.

Common mistakes with timers are:

1. You need to start it with either timer.enabled or timer.start.
2. You might need to reset the timer in the tick handler, depending on the type of timer and property settings. (There is the timer control, system.timers.timer, and system.threading.timer, each of which is a little different.)
3. You might need to disable temporarily it in the tick handler to make sure it doesn't re-enter the handler and cause problems.

More info:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx